# Question about convergence proof, why has he chosen the parameter this way

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

In this proof he says that $n > 2k$, but would it work if $n \ge k$, if not, why?

> If $p>0$ and $\alpha$ is real, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^\alpha}{(1+p)^n}=0$.
>
> **Proof:** Let $k$ be an integer such that $k>\alpha$, $k>0$. For $n>2k$, $$(1+p)^n>\binom{n}kp^k=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}p^k>\frac{n^kp^k}{2^kk!}\;.$$ Hence $$0<\frac{n^\alpha}{(1+p)^n}<\frac{2^kk!}{p^k}n^{\alpha-k}\qquad(n>2k)\;.$$

Comment: The argument would not work, we want the terms upstairs to be $\gt n/2$. But we have given a great deal away, so a more delicate estimate would do the job for large enough $n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ah ofcourse, now i understand, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get

$$n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)>\frac{n^k}{2^k}=\left(\frac{n}2\right)^k$$

in order to get the last inequality in the first displayed line. You’ll have this if $n-k+1\ge\frac{n}2$, i.e., if $n\ge 2k-2$. Taking $n>2k$ is a simple way to ensure this; taking $n\ge 2k-2$ would be good enough. Taking $n\ge k$ would not in general be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @user119615: You’re very welcome!